# What's the Ruby equivalent of Perl's s{}{}e?

Tags: ruby, regex, perl, language-comparisons

I'm trying to rewrite a command to replace output files with the same files in a different directory, building up a translation map. In Perl I could do something like this:

```
s{(-o|--out)\s((?:\S+\/)?(\S+))}{ "$1 " . ($m{$2}="foo/$3") }eg
```

I'm not clear how to do the same under Ruby, because:

```
"-out AAA -out yeah/BBB".
gsub(/((?:\s|^)-out)\s+((?:\S+\/)?(\S+))/) { |f|
  "#{f[1]} #{m[f[2]] = "temp/#{f[3]}"}"
}
```

results in

```
"o temp/t- temp/u"
```

because 'm' is the matched string, not a match object, so `#{m[1]}` is just the second character of the matched string.

I don't want to use `$1`, `$2` because Rubocop says they're evil, and I'd prefer not to use 'Regexp.last_match' because it's quite remarkably verbose and turns this one-liner into a do-block.

Is there no built-in that gives me the match object as the parameter?

Comment: You can use named matches with gsub, so you don't have to rely on `$1` and `$2`. Pass them down to the block as you would any other block arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you do not want to use `$1` as you did in perl, you might use named matches:

```
"-out AAA -out BBB".gsub(/(?<leading>\s|^)(?<out>-out)\s+(?<rest>\S+)/) do
  "#{$~[:leading]}#{$~[:out]} BLOCK"
end
#⇒ "-out BLOCK -out BLOCK"
```

Another option would be to shut rubocop up, since you know what you are doing:

```
#rubocop:disable Style/PerlBackrefs
"-out AAA -out BBB".gsub(/(\s|^)(-out)\s+(\S+)/) do
  "#{$1}#{$2} BLOCK"
end
#rubocop:enable Style/PerlBackrefs
```

Comment: Thanks, I've ended up doing the latter, but I infer from your response that there isn't a gsub that provides the match object as its parameter?

Comment: There is not, unfortunately. Or, one might think it is by design, since you always have an access to global [`$~`](http://rocket-science.ru/tips/2013/02/26/ruby-predefined-globals/#tilde), returning the last successful match. Since ruby was designed single-threaded, `gsub` returning last match seems to be redundant. (All the above is just my assumption.)